# Select usando um array?

Tags: mysql, node.js, select

Eu tenho o seguinte array:

```
var arr = ['A', 'B', 'C'...];
```

E no meu banco de dados eu tenho a coluna `categoria` onde os valores são salvos no seguinte modo: `'A,B,C...'`, como eu poderia fazer um `SELECT` pegando cada categoria do `arr` e encontrando os correspondentes valores do meu banco? Como são tantas categorias, eu gostaria de evitar o uso de um loop no `arr`.

Eu tentei algo tipo:

```
var categorias = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"];
var sql = "SELECT id_item, titulo, resumo, tipo FROM series WHERE categoria IN ('"+categorias.join()+"')";
```

Porém não funciona como em PHP.

Comment: O correto é `('"+categorias.join()+"')`

Comment: Corrigi o código, esqueci de escrever as aspas

Comment: Se os valores são textos, então cada um dentro do `IN` deve vir dentro de aspas, sendo que no caso iria ficar `IN ('A','B','C','D','E')`. Para tal pode usar `map` ou várias outras funções.

Comment: @Isac poderia me fazer um exemplo de como seria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma vez que os valores que está a usar para o `IN` são textos (`varchar`) eles tem de vir dentro de aspas, cada um individualmente, que não é o que acontece no momento para a sua variável `sql`.

Veja por si mesmo:

```js
var categorias = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"];
var sql = "SELECT id_item, titulo, resumo, tipo FROM series WHERE categoria IN ('"+categorias.join()+"')";

console.log(sql);
```

Quando eles deveriam ficar assim: `('A','B','C','D','E')`

Para fazer esta transformação pode utilizar o método [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) por exemplo, para colocar as aspas, antes de fazer o `join` com:

```
categorias.map(cat => `'${cat}'`).join(",")
```

Veja o exemplo a funcionar:

```js
var categorias = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"];
var sql = "SELECT id_item, titulo, resumo, tipo FROM series WHERE categoria IN ("+categorias.map(cat => `'${cat}'`).join(",")+")";

console.log(sql);
```

Note que tive que tirar a aspa inicial e final que tinha colocado manualmente dentro do `IN`. Aproveitei e coloquei o caratere do `join` para tornar mais claro que está a fazer `join` por `,`.